# three.js: When to move / rotate geometry and when mesh?

Tags: three.js

I compose multiple STLs for 3D printing / milling. For that I also use CSG and need some raytracing for detecting features of the models.

My scene is pretty much static. Just have to move around the models to arrange them. For this use case I'm not really sure which approach for moving / rotating the models is right.

Currently I manipulate the BufferGeometries directly. So everything in the geometry is like in the real world. Each position, each normal. No calculation from / to local or world coordinates.

On the other hand I could do the same thing with changing the meshes, which means to change just a matrix.

For me, working with the mesh is more for animation etc. While working with the geometry to manipulate the real object, which is my intention.

I'm wondering when one would translate / rotate the geometry and when the mesh. I know that manipulating the geometry is not best for CPU, which is not a problem for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Geometry can be translated so that subsequent transformations (such as scale or rotation) originate from a more preferred vector. Meshes can share a geometry. There are unique use cases for either if you care to memorize the list. Sometimes I integrate preexisting code samples. Sometimes the decision is made for me by some aspect of the process. As for the properties which may be similar, which is more convenient? I like the pattern of modifying an Object3D dummy using those methods and then updating from its matrix. There's a whole book on normals, but I didn't write it, sadly...